# Can web.py route static content with its builtin server?

Tags: python, http, web.py

web.py comes with a builtin http server which is enough for my testing needs. I have following 2 endpoints defined in server.py.

```
/login
/info
```

My folder structure is like this.

```
app
|__api
|__|__login.py
|__|__info.py
|__|__server.py
|__www
|__|__index.html
|__|__app.js
```

In terminal, I just run following command.

```
$ python app/api/server.py
```

Above setup works but what I want to add is a root (**/**) to go to **www/** and serve index.html. Can I do that with web.py builtin server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrote it myself :)

```
urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'General'
)

class General:
    app_dir = 'www'

    def GET(self, path):
        root = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('.', os.pardir))
        dest = '%s/%s/index.html' % (root, self.app_dir)
        if path:
            dest = '%s/%s/%s' % (root, self.app_dir, path)
        with open(dest, 'r') as f:
            return f.read()
        return ''
```

Comment: Very nice solution!